# 301 Redirections only work for the main domain and not posts or pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I decided to change the domain name on my current website, and did that by changing the main domain and changing the settings in wordpress dashboard. I have both domains connected to the hosting (same on before changing the domain) and I used the .htaccess to redirect the old one to the new one.

Now it works, when I type the old domain, I get sent to the new one. However, my problem is this doesn't work for literally any other link. So if I try to access a post, it does not redirect me to the same page in the new domain.

I have searched everywhere, but I can't seem to solve this. I also use different redirection tools to determine if it works or not, I am not just going off my own network.

Example :

I type:
`https://olddomain.com/blabla/bla-bla-bla/`

I land on :
`https://olddomain.com/blabla/bla-bla-bla/` instead of `https://newdomain.com/blabla/bla-bla-bla/`

The code I am using in my .htaccess file is:

````
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/newdomain\.com\/" [R=301,L] ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you implement a redirection specifically only for the URL with trivial path "/". If you want to redirect *all* possible paths then you need to do so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```

You should place that redirection *before* the internal wordpress rules in case both set's are served from the same location, so configured by the same file. So place the higher up in that file.

I would recommend to start out with a *temporary* redirection (`R=302`) and only to change that to a *permanent* redirection (`R=301`) once you are sure everything works as expected.